# Unit test for a command class

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have a command class for the export button that i wan to test it whit automation unit test.

```
void ICommand.Execute(object parameter)
        {
            string FileName = "";
            if (measurementViewModel.NavigationResolver.ShowSaveFileDialog(ref FileName))
            {
                bool IsFirstMasurement = true;
                foreach (Measurement measurement in measurementViewModel.Measurements)
                {
                    if (measurement.IsSelected)
                    {
                        if (IsFirstMasurement)
                        {
                            measurementViewModel.MeasurementModel.ExportMeasurementToXml(FileName, measurement);

                            IsFirstMasurement = false;
                        }
                        else
                            measurementViewModel.MeasurementModel.AppendMeasurementsToXml(FileName, measurement);
                    }
                }
                measurementViewModel.Measurements.MoveCurrentToPosition(-1);
                measurementViewModel.Measurements.Refresh();
            }
        }
```

I want to test if 1 measurement are selected in the measurement list how measurement export will be exported with export function and if i select 3 measurement from the list, if the export function will export 3 measurement not the hole list of measurement.
I want to focus more on that measurement.is selected function.
Any suggestion are welcome.

I try to create a dummy class for that export function:

```
  public class ExportTest
    {

        MeasurementViewModel measurementViewModel = null;

        public int ExportCounter { get; set; }

        public ExportTest(MeasurementViewModel viewModel)
        {
            this.measurementViewModel = viewModel;

        }


       public void export()
        {
            measurementViewModel.InitializeMeasurements();


            measurementViewModel.MeasurementModel.Measurements.ElementAt(0).IsSelected = true;
            string FileName = "..\\..\\..\\..\\..\\03_Test\\PC-Software\\BackendTest\\PMDtest\\MeasurementTest\\MeasurementModelTest\\test_xml.xml";

                bool IsFirstMasurement = true;
                foreach (Measurement measurement in measurementViewModel.Measurements)
                {
                    if (measurement.IsSelected)
                    {
                        if (IsFirstMasurement)
                        {
                            measurementViewModel.MeasurementModel.ExportMeasurementToXml(FileName, measurement);

                            IsFirstMasurement = false;
                            ExportCounter++;
                        }
                        else
                            measurementViewModel.MeasurementModel.AppendMeasurementsToXml(FileName, measurement);
                    }
                }
                measurementViewModel.Measurements.Refresh();
            }
        }

}
```

And the test class for that function:

```
[TestMethod]
        public void ExportBugTest() 
        {

            DbRepository database = null;
            database = DbRepository.GetInstance();
            database.EstablishConnection("postgres", "1234");
            Assert.IsTrue(database.IsConnected);
            MeasurementViewModel measurementViewModel = new MeasurementViewModel();

            ExportTest exportTest = new ExportTest(measurementViewModel);

            exportTest.export();

            Assert.AreEqual(1, exportTest.ExportCounter);

        }
```

But that assert is always 1 how can i

Comment: We are not going to write the unit tests for you :).  What have you got so far? I can offer suggestions from that point onwards.

Comment: i try to create a dummy class for the export function